# passing arguments to click function in jquery fires the function without clicking

Tags: javascript, jquery, click

Hi
I have a function that makes ajax calls once an element is clicked. I use this code:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
function ajax_call(offset, length) {
$.ajax({method: "get", 
    url: "file.php",
    data: "offset="+ offset,

    success: function(returnedData)
        {     
            $("#content").html(returnedData);
        }
});
}

$("#profile").click(ajax_call(0, 1000));

});
```

The issue is with this line:

`$("#profile").click(ajax_call(0, 1000));`

When I pass arguments to ajax_call function, the function is run once the page loads without any user intervention, however when I remove the arguments like this:
`$("#profile").click(ajax_call);` the function is called only when the element is clicked. I have researched for hours about this issue but with no luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will call the function immediately `ajax_call(0, 1000)` and pass the return value as event handler.

You have to wrap it in an anonymous function:

```
$("#profile").click(function() {
    ajax_call(0, 1000);
});
```

Whenever you have `functionname()` you are actually *calling* the function. `functionname` instead (without parenthesis) gives you a reference to the function. As you cannot just pass `ajax_call` to `click`, you have to wrap it in another function.

So the anonymous function `function(){...}` is passed as event handler and when it gets called, it executes `ajax_call(0, 1000)`.